# Allow underscore "_" as a special character

Tags: c#, regex

This is the expression, it is not accepting "_" as a special character

```
{(?=.{8,})(?=(.*\d){0,})(?=(.*\W){1,})}
```

Comment: You might want to explain what you're trying to do :)

Comment: The above expression accepting atleast one special character except "_" i want that should be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

When you set conditions inside a pattern, do not forget to actually consume the characters, add `.+` to capture 1 or more symbols, or `.*` to capture 0 or more characters:

```
{(?=.{8,})(?=(.*\d){0,})(?=(.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]){1,}).+}
```

However, if you want to require a string to have at least 1 digit and at least 1 non-word symbol (excluding underscore), I'd suggest using

```
{(?=.{8,})(?=(?:.*\d){0,})(?=(?:.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]){1,}).+}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jO3yJ8/2).

Comment: Thank you so much,

but my concern was it is not accepting "_"  as a special character it is accepting that as a normal character.

and as we know we use underscore widely as a special character

Comment: However, `\w` will consider `_` as a alphanumeric character, alongside  A-Za-z0-9.

Comment: @Docteur: Could you explain? `.` will match `_`, there is no `\w` in my pattern. And yes, `\w` matches `_`.

Comment: @stribizhev I was only answering the comment "and as we know we use underscore widely as a special character"! I wasn't referring to your answer, sorry! :-)

Comment: @user2078643: my regex matches the underscore, please check it works for you. Also, please add your attempts to the question body, or the question will be closed and perhaps, further downvoted.

Comment: One more questions

how to add "_"(underscore) in  (?=(.*\W)
as it does not accept _ as a special character

Comment: You can expand this `\W` into `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` then.